# Error code 1241 operand should contain 1 column(s) from insert

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to insert some data into my table employees but I'm getting the error code 1241 operand should contain 1 column(s)

```
INSERT INTO Employees 
(Staff_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Home_Contact, Mobile_Contact, Address, Birth_date, Sex, Date_Started, Job_Rank, Job_title, Job_Type, Salary, Department_ID) 
VALUES (1, 'Cameron', 'Robson', 123520, 253652, 'Mars\,Avenue', 01/01/0210, 'M', 01/05/0610, 'Senior', 'System analyst', 'Expert', 5000, 2)
```

everything seems fine to me....

Comment: `01/01/0210` => `'01/01/0210'` Date literals should be quoted with `'`

Comment: my data type for birth date and date started is set to DATE

Comment: i would get incorrect data type rather than error code 1241 right?

Comment: Are you certain that this code as is is generating the error message? How are you executing it? It might e.g. be an escaping problem, a misused multiquery, .... (Although you definitely need to review your date format, it should not generate this error).

Comment: Quote your date. It doesn't matter the TYPE of the column. Date Literals are quoted in mysql. And what kind of crazy date is `01/01/0210` You had people born in 210 AD?

Comment: i figured it out, my trigger was causing this, thanks for the answers anyway

Comment: If you don't quote the date literals they will be interpreted as arithmetic expressions.